# How to detect and make hyperlinks/mentions/hashtags clickable in UILabel?

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel

How to detect and make link/mention/hashtag clickable in UILabel. Alternatively, is there any open source library that I can utilize (I already looked at Fancy UILabel which doesn't handle multiline tex, TTAttributedLabel which doesn't handle mention/hashtag)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do so with UILabel in the current iOS...

TTTAttributedLabel will let you style up your label, however for clickable (or rather - *tappable*) links you should rather either use a UIWebView and style it in such a was as to disguise it as a Label, or, you could get geeky and split your labels up and use a UIButton in the mix, but that's very messy - like a puzzle, only... they don't fit together.

Last option you might have is to overlay a UIButton over a link, but this requires that you know where the link is and since the question was about **detecting** links etc...

You should really look into UIWebView.

Comment: TTTAttributedLabel indeed provides you to make it tappable, but it can't handle the custom links (e.g. mention, hashtag). I ended up using UIWebView as it seems to be more intuitive/doable than other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using following library:

https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel

Comment: STTweetLabel is not working in ios 6.0 any other way or alternate way for this ?