# How to detect if there is a Link in UILabel text and make it clickable - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am using a `UILabel` to contain some text. This text may sometimes contain some links like **http://www.google.com** or **www.google.com** or even **google.com**. How do I detect these links and make the text clickable to open in a browser. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: misleading answer... pls check...

Comment: In Objective-C, I've made a `UILabel` clickable to perform a segue by adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I added the `gestureRecognizer` to my `UILabel` and set `userInteraction` to `enabled`. I don't think it would be much more trouble to treat it as a hyperlink. As Rocky said, you could also change it to a `UITextView`, turn on link detection, and call it a day. I'm not sure about the rest of your issue, but hopefully the making a `UILabel` do something is helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect and make hyperlinks/mentions/hashtags clickable in UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459997/how-to-detect-and-make-hyperlinks-mentions-hashtags-clickable-in-uilabel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a UITextView instead and set detection for links:

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

> textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes()